# NUnit test dies with SerializationException but works fine if not run under NUnit

Tags: .net, f#, nunit

I have a bit of f# code (below) that takes a unit->obj and evaluates it in its own appdomain. The motivation is that I need to free assemblies loaded during the evaluation. The code appears to work fine, at least on the trivial examples I have tried. However, it fails with an exception when called from an NUnit test. The exception and code are below. I'll be most grateful for any help.

> Sandbox.trivial_test:
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Type is not
>   resolved for member 'Sandbox+myDelegate@28,sandboxtest,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

```
module Sandbox

open System

type IsolationRunner (f:unit->obj) = 
    inherit System.MarshalByRefObject ()

    let mutable storedResult : obj option = None

    member x.callback () : unit =
       let res = f ()
       storedResult <- Some res

    member x.result : obj =
       match storedResult with
         None -> failwith "No result yet"
       | Some x -> x

let run_code_in_own_appdomain (f: unit -> obj) : obj =        
        let appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain "MyTempDomain"
        try
            let ir = IsolationRunner f
            let myDelegate = new CrossAppDomainDelegate (fun () -> ir.callback ())
            appDomain.DoCallBack myDelegate
            ir.result
        finally
            AppDomain.Unload appDomain


open NUnit.Framework

[<Test>]
let trivial_test () =
    let actual = run_code_in_own_appdomain (fun x -> 123 |> box) |> unbox
    printf "result is %O\n" actual
    Assert.AreEqual (123, actual)
```

Comment: Do your code and the NUnit library/test runner both reference the same version of the .NET runtime?

Comment: I think they do. All tests that don't touch the newly made appdomain still pass fine. Also, even the failing tests work fine if use the current appdomain instead (and don't do the unload). Many thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: that sounds very much like there is a problem in the appdomain interaction. You need to show that the *exact same* code works when run directly (as .exe) but doesn't work when run under NUnit. e.g. by both variants calling one and only one method which implements the test case. Also, I'm of the opinion that support requests for products should go first to the product's mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind netizens of NUnit-Discuss suggested a solution. Briefly, just let path be the location (i.e. directory) of the executable, then create the other domain as:

> AppDomain.CreateDomain ("MyTempDomain", null, path, "", false)